# Не получается поменять версию SDK в Android приложении

Tags: android, sdk

Не получается изменить версию API проекта на 25. С помощью Android SDK скачала версию API 25 а в свойствах проекта не дает на нее поменять, максимум 24. Если вручную в build.gradle на 25 заменить ошибки. Версия JDK стоит 1.8.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

build.gradle:

```
   apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.ann.myhouse"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
  // compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'


    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.4.0'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.4.0'
    compile 'com.thoughtbot:expandablerecyclerview:1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
}
```

Comment: Скиньте свой билд.гредл

Comment: добавила код градл

Answer (score 1):

После перезагрузки компьютера проблема не воспроизводится.

Answer (score 0):

У вас должны совпадать мажорные версии этих штук:

```
buildToolsVersion 
compileSdkVersion 
targetSdkVersion
```

А также версии бибилиотек поддержи `com.android.support:...`

Т.е. при повышении с 24 на 25 у вас должны все вышеперечисленные быть 25 версии

Comment: да они совпадают